# C# SQL INSERT INTO query and displaying result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am using VS2005 and SQL Server 2005.

I am trying to execute multiple `INSERT INTO` SQL statements which connect 3 sql tables.

The 3 tables are:

- `Table1`: `UserID, Username`
- `Table2`: `UserID, Status`
- `Table3`: `UserID, Username, Issue`

The following are the checks that I need to perform:

1. Users that exist in `Table1` should exist in `Table2`
2. Users that exist in `Table1` should not have `STATUS=DELETE` in `Table2`
3. Users that do not have `STATUS=DELETE` in `Table2` should exist in `Table1`

Currently I only have a `SELECT` statement which fulfills the above 3 queries, without adding in the 3rd table:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
OR (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
OR (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status <> 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
```

I would like to, for each check above, `INSERT` the results into `Table3` with a unique `ISSUE` variable (e.g. for check no.1, `ISSUE=User exist in t1 but not t2`)

Currently I am trying to form a query which connects the 3 tables together, and for each result found by the first check, `t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL`, it will insert a new row into `Table3`. But I am having some problems with the SQL query.

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (userid, username, issue) 
VALUES (t1.userid, t1.username, 'user not found in t2')
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have these tables for testing, so the syntax will be close:

The `COALESCE` for the `UserId` will ensure that you have a value inserted into the column, since you are not sure if the value will exist in Table1 or in Table2

I also just used your where clauses for the `CASE` statements to fill the `Issue` column.  You can update the text to suit your application.

```
INSERT INTO Table3(UserId, Username, Issue)
SELECT COALESCE(t1.UserId, t2.UserId), t1.UserName
   , CASE
        WHEN (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
           THEN 'User exists in t1 but not in t2'
        WHEN (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
           THEN 'User Exists in t1, but status in t2 is not DELETE'
        WHEN (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
           THEN 'Non-Deleted user in t2 does not exist in t1'
     END
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
   OR (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
   OR (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
```

Comment: hi Adam, thanks for the great help. I would like to ask, what if I would like to retrieve the variable 'Status' from t2 as well and put it in my t3 to display? Where do I add it in the query?

Comment: Currently your specifications do not show a column in Table3 for status.  If you added one, you could simply put `, t2.status` after the case statement for the `issue` column.  You could also concatenate the `t2.status` value into the `issue` column, using `'your existing string And Current User Status = "' + t2.status + '"'` to wrap the status in double quotes.  This also easily lets you see if it was empty, as you'll have `..Status = ""`

Comment: Thanks Adam! I have successfully added the status column and variable from your help. I googled about checking duplicates in SQL, but some articles says that it is not possible. Is it possible to integrate a SQL check which checks for duplicated keys with an without case sensitivity?

Comment: @RUiHAO, I believe you've asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132763/c-sharp-sql-adding-a-query-check-for-duplicated-key and I have provided an answer there for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
1.
    Insert in to Table3(userid,issue)
        SELECT t1.userid,'check no.1'
        FROM table1 t1
        FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
        where t1.userid not null and t2.userid is null
2.
    Insert in to Table3(userid,issue)
        SELECT t1.userid,'check no.2'
        FROM table1 t1
        inner JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
        where t2.status = 'DELETE'

3.
    Insert in to Table3(userid,issue)
        SELECT t2.userid,'check no.3'
        FROM table1 t1
        right outer JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
        where t2.status = 'DELETE' and t1.userid is null
```

Comment: your code is a much simplified version and I could understand it perfectly! Is it possible to do a check on duplicated keys (e.g. userid) on t1 and t2 base on with and without case sensitivity?

Comment: Hi RedHat, why do you use RIGHT OUTER JOIN on the 3rd check? Users that Status!=Delete should exist in t1