# C# SQL Adding a query check for duplicated key

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to add a query in my current SQL INSERT INTO statement. Below is my table and current sql statement.

I have 3 tables:

*Table1*: **UserID**, **Username**.

*Table2*: **UserID**, **Status**.

*Table3*: **UserID**, **Username**, **Issue**

Currently I only have 3 SELECT statement which fulfills the above 3 checks and INSERT the result into Table3:

```
 1.
    Insert in to Table3(userid,issue)
        SELECT t1.userid,'check no.1'
        FROM table1 t1
        FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
        where t1.userid not null and t2.userid is null
2.
    Insert in to Table3(userid,issue)
        SELECT t1.userid,'check no.2'
        FROM table1 t1
        inner JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
        where t2.status = 'DELETE'

3.
    Insert in to Table3(userid,issue)
        SELECT t2.userid,'check no.3'
        FROM table2 t2
        right outer JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
        where t2.status <> 'DELETE' and t1.userid is null
```

Now I wish to add in another additional check which is to check for duplicated userid in BOTH T1 AND T2:

1. Check for same userid with same caps (e.g. E01 and E01 should not exist)
2. Check for same userid but different caps (e.g. E01 and e01 should not exist)

How can I code the 4th sql query which specially checks for duplicated userids?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: By default SQL queries are not case sensitive.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: risky statement - case sensitivity in SQL Server depends on the **collation** used for the database, table and/or column .... it **can** be case-sensitive or case-insensitive...

Comment: @Mark Care to place a wager on whether his collation is case sensitive?  I'm down for making some fast cash :)

But yes, I know you are correct.

Comment: @BrandonMoore So it is impossible for me to check for case sensitivity? Is it possible if I want to check for duplicates then?

Comment: No, it's not impossible.  You can specify a collation in your query, but by default it's not case sensitive (unless the collation for your db is set to a case sensitive one, but that's unlikely).  It looks like you don't want it to be case sensitive though so this default behavior is what you want, right?

Comment: A good code example will be good for me, as I do not know how to integrate it to my current sql statement :)

Comment: A quick way to check case is just cast everything to lower case, if you dont want to allow E01 and E01 or E01 and e01  just cast both to lower case then all you have to do is check if the value you are inserting matches one in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

```
INSERT INTO Table3(userid, Username, issue)
SELECT 
    userid, Username, 'Duplicate UserID' 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
                userid, 
                Username, 
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY userid) AS [RANK] 
        FROM 
            Table1 --table2
    ) X
WHERE 
    [RANK]=2


INSERT INTO Table3(userid, Username, issue)
SELECT 
    userid, [status], 'Duplicate UserID' 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
                userid, 
                [status], 
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY userid) AS [RANK] 
        FROM 
            Table2
    ) X
WHERE 
    [RANK]=2
```

You can use the COLLATE as shown in the OLD section to do a case sensitive check, if you need.

I used RANK=2 to insert only one entry for duplicate userID

OLD:
You can use the COLLATE to do a case sensitive check

```
INSERT INTO Table3(UserId, Username, Issue)
    SELECT 
    COALESCE(t1.UserId, t2.UserId), 
    t1.UserName,
    CASE        
        WHEN (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
            THEN 'User exists in t1 but not in t2'
        WHEN (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
            THEN 'User Exists in t1, but status in t2 is DELETE'
        WHEN (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
            THEN 'Non-Deleted user in t2 does not exist in t1'
        WHEN t1.userid COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS = t2.userid COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
            THEN 'Duplicate userid with same caps'
        WHEN t1.userid = t2.userid
            THEN 'Duplicate userid but different caps'
     END
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE 
    (t1.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid = t2.userid) OR    
    (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL) OR 
    (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL) OR 
    (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
```

Comment: Hi Riji, I apologize for not explaining myself clearly. I am trying to achieve duplicated records within each table, *Table1* and *Table2* individually, not by comparing both tables together. I'm sorry, and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The unique userId constraint is probably best enforced with a `UNIQUE INDEX` (should help performance as well), but to ensure you do not request a duplicate be entered, this should help you:  I used `LEFT JOIN` into table3 to check that the value is currently null (record does not exist)

This code will ignore duplicates, and not insert a record

```
INSERT INTO Table3(UserId, Username, Issue)
SELECT COALESCE(t1.UserId, t2.UserId), t1.UserName
       , CASE
            WHEN (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
               THEN 'User exists in t1 but not in t2'
            WHEN (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
               THEN 'User Exists in t1, but status in t2 is DELETED'
            WHEN (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
               THEN 'Non-Deleted user in t2 does not exist in t1'
         END AS Issue
    FROM table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
    LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3user ON t1.UserID = t3user.UserId
    LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3status ON t2.UserId = t3status.UserId
    WHERE t3user.UserId IS NULL
       AND t3status.UserId IS NULL
       AND
       (
          (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
          OR (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
          OR (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
       )
```

If you wish to insert a record indicating a duplicate, you could use the following:

```
INSERT INTO Table3(UserId, Username, Issue)
SELECT COALESCE(t1.UserId, t2.UserId), t1.UserName
       , CASE
            WHEN (t3user.UserId IS NOT NULL OR t3Status.UserId IS NOT NULL)
               THEN 'Duplicated userid found: "' + t1.UserId + '"'
            WHEN (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
               THEN 'User exists in t1 but not in t2'
            WHEN (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
               THEN 'User Exists in t1, but status in t2 is DELETE'
            WHEN (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
               THEN 'Non-Deleted user in t2 does not exist in t1'
         END AS Issue
    FROM table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
    LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3user ON t1.UserID = t3user.UserId
    LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3status ON t2.UserId = t3status.UserId
    WHERE 

       (
          (t2.userid IS NULL AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
          OR (t2.status = 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NOT NULL)
          OR (t2.userid IS NOT NULL AND t2.status != 'DELETE' AND t1.userid IS NULL)
       )
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. With reference to your code, what will happen when a duplicated userid is found?

Comment: I would like to identify all duplicates instead of ignoring them, like the issues above for the 3 checks, and give duplicated keys an issue like e.g. 'Duplicated userid found'.

Comment: Let me know if this is what you were hoping for.

Comment: Now that is corrected, does the rest of the query give you what you wanted?

Comment: I am still converting all the variables to my usage, will take awhile :)

Comment: I have converted the code to my usage. However, it still does not identify the duplicated userid when one of my database has duplicated IDs

Comment: If you want to put that information into the Issue column, you can concatenate t1.UserId into the Issue field.  Depending on your version of SQL, it might look like: `THEN 'Duplicated userid found: "' + t1.UserId + '"'` I will also update my answer with this.

Comment: Hi Adam, I have decided to use a simplified version of the sql queries. I have successfully implemented the above 3 into my code. Now I am trying to develop a 4th one which checks for duplicated userids in both t1 and t2

Answer (score 0):

As people have commented - case sensitivity is set through collation.

As for checking for duplicate keys - you can use the [EXISTS keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx).
Something like this:

```
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE userid=t1.UserID)
   THEN -- DO WHATEVER
```

However, if you are willing to disable inserting duplicate IDs, you should do it by setting a Primary Key/Unique Index instead.

EDIT:
Query to find duplicates in Table1:

```
Insert into Table3(userid,issue)
SELECT t1.userid,'Duplicate in table1'
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 _t1 WHERE _t1.userid = t1.userid) > 1
```

For duplicates in Table 2 query will be very similar.

Comment: how can i integrate your code into my current code such that if a duplicated userid is found in Table1 and Table2, it will insert the userid, username and issue (duplicated userid found) into Table3?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you mean: You want to insert the line to Table3 if and only if both Table1 and Table2 contain the same userID?

Comment: Nope. I want to insert the record in only when a duplicated record is found within each *Table1* and *Table2* itself. Thus, the issues will be 'Duplicated record found in Table1', and 'Duplicated record found in Table2'. Thank you